# MKmapView.overlays return nil - Crash

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkoverlay

Self.mapView.overlays return nil instead of [],

this is causing a crash.

crash func:

```
fileprivate func addRadiusToUserLocation(userCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D,radius : Double) {
    let radiusCircle = MKCircle(center: userCoordinate, radius: radius)
    self.mapView.removeOverlays(self.mapView.overlays)
    self.mapView.addOverlays([radiusCircle])
}
```

stack:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
*** -[__NSSetM removeObject:]: object cannot be nil
0  CoreFoundation                 0x18307bd38 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x182590528 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x183014c44 _CFArgv
3  CoreFoundation                 0x182f46264 -[__NSCFString hash]
4  VectorKit                      0x193139ca8 -[VKRasterOverlayTileSource removeOverlay:]
5  VectorKit                      0x192dc74b8 -[VKMapModel removeRasterOverlay:]
6  MapKit                         0x19342b7f0 -[MKOverlayContainerView _removeDrawable:forOverlay:level:]
7  MapKit                         0x19342acd0 -[MKOverlayContainerView removeOverlay:]
8  MapKit                         0x19342adc8 -[MKOverlayContainerView removeOverlays:]
9                        0x10429bfd8 SiteMapManager.addRadiusToUserLocation(userCoordinate:radius:) (SiteMapManager.swift:156)
10                       0x10429d184 specialized SiteMapManager.addOrUpdateUserLocation(userLocation:radius:) (SiteMapManager.swift:48)
11                       0x10429f1cc specialized SiteMapManager.mapView(_:viewFor:) (SiteMapManager.swift:203)
12                       0x10429c164 @objc SiteMapManager.mapView(_:viewFor:) (SiteMapManager.swift)
13 MapKit                         0x1933e99e8 -[MKMapView annotationManager:representationForAnnotation:]
14 MapKit                         0x1933a7ba4 -[MKAnnotationManager _addRepresentationForAnnotation:]
15 MapKit                         0x1933a68f0 -[MKAnnotationManager updateVisibleAnnotations]
16 MapKit                         0x1933c1620 -[MKMapView _didChangeRegionMidstream:]
17 MapKit                         0x1933dddf0 -[MKMapView mapLayer:didChangeRegionAnimated:]
18 VectorKit                      0x192d90690 -[VKMapView map:didChangeRegionAnimated:]
19 VectorKit                      0x192d3fc74 -[VKMapCameraController rotateToYaw:withPoint:animated:]
20 VectorKit                      0x192df7d84 -[VKMapCameraController snapMapIfNecessary:]
21 MapKit                         0x19342b7f0 -[MKOverlayContainerView _removeDrawable:forOverlay:level:]
22 MapKit                         0x19342acd0 -[MKOverlayContainerView removeOverlay:]
23 MapKit                         0x19342adc8 -[MKOverlayContainerView removeOverlays:]
24                       0x10429bfd8 SiteMapManager.addRadiusToUserLocation(userCoordinate:radius:) (SiteMapManager.swift:156)
```

addRadiusToUserLocation call in:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
```

mapView:

```
@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seams like a threading issue.

I was able to fix it with moving addoverlay and removeoverlay to the main thread.

```
fileprivate func addRadiusToUserLocation(userCoordinate: 
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   CLLocationCoordinate2D,radius : Double) {
   let radiusCircle = MKCircle(center: userCoordinate, radius: radius)
   self.mapView.removeOverlays(self.mapView.overlays)
   self.mapView.addOverlays([radiusCircle])
}
```

}

Comment: Great! Saved me.

Answer (score -1):

You need check if your mapview overlays is not nil  before remove it

```
fileprivate func addRadiusToUserLocation(userCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D,radius : Double) {
    let radiusCircle = MKCircle(center: userCoordinate, radius: radius)
    if(self.mapView.overlays != nil){
         self.mapView.removeOverlays(self.mapView.overlays)
    }
    self.mapView.addOverlays([radiusCircle])
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, but why it nil?? in apple documentation It's supposed to return an empty array.

Comment: Its seems that when you call your function your mapview is nil, can you check that? @Yairhadad put a print(self.mapView) and check if its nil in your method call

Comment: Or you are setting this array value to nil in some part of your code? @Yairhadad

Comment: The mapView isn't nil, I check it, and the event in the stack get into the mapView func - 23 MapKit [MKOverlayContainerView removeOverlays:]

Comment: There is no place in the app that the overlays is changed except for this func.

Comment: Well @Yairhadad then use my answer and fix your issue, I don't know what can be happening or why your .overlays is nil without more info

Comment: This won't work because `Comparing non-optional value of type '[MKOverlay]' to nil always returns true`

Comment: @Nico, at that point in 2017 that was a problem, maybe a bug from Apple but if now this don't happen better, (read the first line of question), are you having this problem?

Comment: Yes I'm getting the same error. `[__NSSetM removeObject:]: object cannot be nil`. In my case I have a polyline drawn on the map and when I tilt the map into 3D it crashes

Comment: Seems that you are removing an object that is nil at that point, check which part of your code have access to change that object @NicoS.

Comment: can you post a question about you specific case? @NicoS.